# Combine two lists into one multidimensional list

Tags: python, list

I would like to merge two lists into one 2d list.

```
list1=["Peter", "Mark", "John"]
list2=[1,2,3]
```

into

```
list3=[["Peter",1],["Mark",2],["John",3]]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
list3 = [list(a) for a in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative:

```
>>> map(list,zip(list1,list2))
[['Peter', 1], ['Mark', 2], ['John', 3]]
```

or in python3:

```
>>> list(map(list,zip(list1,list2)))
[['Peter', 1], ['Mark', 2], ['John', 3]]
```

(you can omit the outer list()-cast in most circumstances, though)

Answer (score 0):

I actually used:

```
list3a = np.concatenate((list1, list2))
list3 = np.reshape(list3a, (-1,2))
```

because otherwise I get the error: 'list indices must be integers, not tuples' when trying to reference the array.

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` iterates over both lists in sync and you will get `a` and `b` in parallel. Both values then create a new list as an element of the final list (`list3`).

```
list3 = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```