# i get this Error: must be str, not generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python and here is a piece of my code

```
with open("Create indicators.sas", "rt") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace((m for m in num_list),( n for n in num_list2)))
```

where num_list is a list of words and num_list2 is another list of words that i need replace.

When I try to run my whole code, I get the following message:

TypeError: must be str, not generator

Comment: `replace` just replaces one string with another. If you need it to work for list of strings, use regex / loop based replace. @Humberto

Comment: Always include the full stack trace in questions about errors. You should also include anything someone answering a question needs to execute your code, in this case you should provide `num_list` and `num_list2`. Those things will help people help you.

Comment: Surrounding the list comprehensions in square brackets (e.g `[m for m in num_list]`) will fix your error. However, `replace` does not take a list. You need to iterate over each item in your list and replace it with its respective item in the other list). Furthermore, you don't actually need to perform list comprehension because I assume that `num_list` and `num_list2` are already lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/q/12624623/8593865    
replacements = zip(num_list, num_list)

with open("Create indicators.sas", "rt") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            for before, after in replacements:
                fout.write(line.replace(before, after)
```

## Explanation:

What this does is first, merges the two lists so that you get one where each item is a sublist. The first item in the sublist being what you want to replace and the second being its replacement.

`for before, after in replacements:` unpacks these two items and lets you use them as variables

`replace` doesn't take lists, although its a neat idea. You have to call `replace` for every string you want to find and replace. The original error you were getting is because list comprehensions are generator objects unless you convert them to a list or tuple and `replace` doesn't take `generators`. However, your code wouldn't have functioned properly anyway because you cannot batch replace substrings in a string like that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace each occurrence of a word from `num_list` with the *corresponding* word from `num_list2`, you can use `zip` and multiple calls to `replace`:

```
pairs = zip(num_list, num_list2)
with open("Create indicators.sas", "rt") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            for old, new in pairs:
                line = line.replace(old, new)
            fout.write(line)
```